# How to make '?' equal a number, so when i go through a list. It will count it as a zero. (Python)

Tags: python, excel, list, variables

As the title says, I want it to read the "?" from an excel sheet and count it as a zero when it goes over it.

```
for eachLine in train:
    tempList=eachLine.split(',')
    avg0=float(tempList[0])
    ageL.append(avg0)
    avg1=float(tempList[1])
    sL.append(avg1)
    avg2=float(tempList[2])
    rbsL.append(avg2)
    avg3=float(tempList[3])
    fbsL.append(avg3)
    avg4=float(tempList[4])
    ogtL.append(avg4)
    avg5=float(tempList[5])
    hemo.append(avg5)
```

I know its ugly, but it works for me. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What language are you programming in ??

Comment: @Gary'sStudent, Python. My bad.

Comment: How does the data look like (train)?

Comment: a couple columns with numbers in them. Nothing weird. Just one of them has a question mark and I cant figure out a way to get that read as a zero.  @rkatkam

Answer (score 2):

If I understand what you want to do you should create a function to parse each cell and return either a float of the value or check for a question mark.

```
def parse_cell(cell):
    try:
        return float(cell)
    except ValueError:
        if cell == "?":
            return 0.0
        raise
```

Then replace each float call with this function i.e.

```
avg0 = parse_cell(tempList[0])
```

Answer (score -1):

```
directory = [ageL, sL, rbsL, fbsL, ogtL, hemo]
for eachLine in train:
    tempList=eachLine.split(',')
    for idx, data in tempList:
        try:
            directory[idx].append(float(data))
        except ValueError:
            directory[idx].append(0.)
```

Comment: How does this answer the question asked?

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.